# Title of 2000s TV show where teens had a video game similar to the Metaverse

Tags: story-identification, tv

I have been looking for this live action show for well over 10 years now, I think. I saw a few episodes somewhere between 2008-2010 but the show may have been a few years older. I watched it on Sci-Fi. The description sounds vague at first but by the end you will know what I'm talking about if you know the show.

It takes place in a futuristic world. I don't think it was Earth as I remember characters from multiple invented planets. I don't recall any makeup or heavy prosthetics. Everyone looked human.

I believe the plot begins with us seeing a teen girl in a video game that is similar to the metaverse. She's at a party or concert, I think, looking for a friend that I believe she eventually finds and briefly speaks with before being called downstairs by her mother in real life and signing off. Shortly after, she gets into a fight with her mom. She says something nasty and her mom slaps her so she angrily leaves.
Her mother believed she was going to school but it becomes apparent to the viewer that she actually intends to run away.

We later see the girl on a train sending her mom a message saying something like "don't live in regret, I forgive you" and before it completely sends, a bomb goes off on the train.

Eventually the police think that the girl had something to do with the attack because of the cryptic message she sent her mother.

A bunch of other stuff happens but it was so long ago, the other memories aren't strong enough to describe.

Comment: The 2000s metaverse was called "Second Life". It's still on. It's basically Metaverse with better graphics, but without the Facebook hype.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is the TV show [*Caprica*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caprica), a prequel spinoff of the rebooted *Battlestar Galactica*. Wikipedia's plot summary of the first two episodes includes several of the elements you remember:

A bomb on a train:

> However, Lacy has second thoughts just as Zoe and Ben board an elevated mag-lev train. On board, Ben reveals a suicide-bomber jacket, which he detonates in the name of the one true god, killing himself, Zoe, and many other passengers.

A metaverse "party or concert" (actually a VR nightclub):

> Struggling to come to terms with the loss of their child, Daniel discovers that Zoe had created a sentient digital avatar of herself that exists in a teenage virtual reality nightclub, accessed via a Holoband.

Police thinking that the character was involved with the bombing:

> [Zoe's mother] is approached by Agent Jordan Duram, a Global Defense Department officer investigating the case, but she initially rejects his assertion that Zoe was involved with the terrorists

Multiple planets, but no makeup or prosthetics (the twelve colonies are twelve separate planets):

> It is 58 years before the Fall, and the planet Caprica is one of the Twelve Colonies of Humanity.

The pilot was released in April 2009, with the season beginning in January 2010, which matches up with your "2008–2010" timeframe.

I also found this official clip from the show, which shows the train bombing and the character Zoe sending a message almost identical to the one you remember: "Don't live in regret, Mom. I forgive you".

Comment: You're a rockstar! That's exactly it, thanks so much.